# Gitlab pipeline jobs are invisible

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops

These are my Gitlab pipelines

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
stages:
    - Trigger

deploy:
    stage: Trigger
    trigger:
        strategy: depend
        include:
            -   local: ci/deploy.gitlab-ci.yml
    variables:
        ENVIRONMENT: "MyEnvironment"
    rules:
        -   if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
            when: on_success

        -   when: never
```

**ci/deploy.gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
include:
    -   local: ci/templates/terraform.gitlab-ci.yml
```

**ci/templates/terraform.gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
include:
    -   template: Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
    TF_ROOT: ./terraform
    TF_STATE_NAME: $ENVIRONMENT
    
   # some more TF_VAR_XXX variables 

stages:
    - Test
    - Infra
    - Cleanup

validate:
    extends: .terraform:validate
    stage: Test

plan:
    extends: .terraform:build
    stage: Infra
    environment:
        name: $ENVIRONMENT
        action: prepare

apply:
    extends: .terraform:deploy
    stage: Infra
    needs:
        - plan
    dependencies:
        - plan
    environment:
        name: $ENVIRONMENT
        url: https://$DOMAIN_NAME
        action: start
    variables:
        TF_AUTO_DEPLOY: 1
    rules:
        -   when: on_success

destroy:
    extends: .terraform:destroy
    stage: Cleanup
    needs:
        - apply
    environment:
        name: $ENVIRONMENT
        action: stop
    rules:
        -   when: manual
```

When I manually run a pipeline using the web interface, I get the following error
`Unable to create pipeline: jobs config should contain at least one visible job`

It looks like the jobs are somehow not included. I have a very similar pipeline in another project in the same group and everything works fine.

Comment: We cannot test your pipeline. Narrow done to a minimal repro case, please.

Comment: According to the rules, no jobs will run unless the pipeline is manually triggered. It could be because of that

Comment: @RaglandAsir 
> When I manually run a pipeline using the web interface, I get the following error Unable to create pipeline: jobs config should contain at least one visible job